# flutter setState not re-render my child stateful widget

Tags: flutter, widget, setstate, stateful

This is my code

```
   var _showGoogleMaps = false;

   @override
   void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () => setState(() {
    _showGoogleMaps = true;
    } ));

   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  return 
  // example 1

  /

/ _showGoogleMaps ? Container(height: 500, color: Colors.blue)
      //          : Container(height: 500, color: Colors.red);

  // example 2
  FullImageView(
  imgCodeVal: imgCodeVal,
  child: Container(height: 500, color: _showGoogleMaps ? Colors.blue : Colors.red));
}  


class FullImageView extends StatefulWidget {
  final ValueListenable<String> imgCodeVal;
  final Widget child;
  FullImageView({Key key, this.imgCodeVal, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
 _FullImageViewState createState() => _FullImageViewState();
}

class _FullImageViewState extends State<FullImageView> {
  String _imgCode;
  Widget _child;

  double _height = 0;

  bool _showImage = false;

 @override
 void initState() { 
    super.initState();
   _child = widget.child;
}

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack( children: [
      _child
  )))))
]);
 }
}
```

In example 1, the container color will change from red to blue after 2 seconds.

But in example 2, the color is red and not changed. FullImageView is just a normal stateful widget

I dont understand why.
Anyone knows the reason. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure example 2 is not working? I tried it out and it works for me both ways.

Comment: @JigarPatel You mean The color changes from red to blue in example 2?

Comment: Yes, it does change.

Comment: @JigarPatel . I added my FullImageView widget code. Maybe it wrong somewhere here. Please compare to your code